# mouseenter works, mouseleave does not

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having trouble with my mouseenter and mouseleave. Ive looked up examples on stack and yt but haven't found anything useful. Im assuming I have to make two functions or maybe just refactor into one. Either way any help is appreciated. I have already declared in the html element itself the height and width at 50px. If you need me to be more specific cool. Im not a professional at javascript so don't get upset that I didn't notice something. If i did just explain to me so i know for future reference. Thanks!

```js
var modWidth;
$('#icons a img').on('mouseenter', function(){
  $(this).width(modWidth);
  $(this).height(modWidth);
  var modWidth = 75;
});


$('#icons a img').on('mouseleave', function(){
  $(this).width(modWidth);
  $(this).height(modWidth);
  var modWidth = 50;
});
```

Comment: You only need to declare this variable once `modWidth`

Comment: No need for second var declaration in mouseleave or mouseenter

Comment: Actually you're passing `undefined` to `.width` and `.height` in all cases. See [Function scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Function_scope) and [Hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xuyxm2ov/ just this, you don't need to redeclare the variable everytime, else you are confusing the scopes of the variable. Also, i think the indended behavior is that when you zoom (mouseover) the picture it gets bigger, so here it is (currently the opposite would happen)

Comment: ahh i see thank you very much.  and yes it was, shouldve added the intended behavior of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to declare `modWidth` once, other then that you will need to set a number to `modWidth` before using it, see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kvb5hb6f/1/

```
  var modWidth;

  $('#demo').on('mouseenter', function() {
    modWidth = 75;
    $(this).width(modWidth);
    $(this).height(modWidth);
  });

  $('#demo').on('mouseleave', function() {
    modWidth = 50;
    $(this).width(modWidth);
    $(this).height(modWidth);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're *shadowing* the `modWidth` variable by creating a new one inside of each function. For example:

```js
var myName = 'Mike';
function bob() {
  var myName = 'Bob';
  console.log('My name is ' + myName);
}

bob();
// Notice that `bob` does not overwrite the original `myName`
// It created a new `myName` in it's own scope
console.log('My name is ' + myName);
```

To avoid that, only declare `modWidth` once.

```js
var modWidth;
$('#icons a img').on('mouseenter', function() {
  $(this).width(modWidth);
  $(this).height(modWidth);
  modWidth = 50; // Notice that I removed `var`
});


$('#icons a img').on('mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).width(modWidth);
  $(this).height(modWidth);
  modWidth = 75; // Notice that I removed `var`
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="icons">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/50x50">
  </a>
</div>
```